# Adding in-between column in csv Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

I work with csv files and it seems python provides a lot of flexibility for handling csv files.

I found several questions linked to my issue, but I cannot figure out how to combine the solutions effectively...

My starting point CSV file looks like this (note there is only 1 column in the 'header' row):

```
FILE1
Z1 20 44 3
Z1 21 44 5
Z1 21 44 8
Z1 22 45 10
```

What I want to do is add a column in between cols #1 and #2, and keep the rest unchanged. This new column has the same # rows as the other columns, but contains the same integer for all entries (10 in my example below). Another important point is I don't really know the number of rows, so I might have to count the # rows somehow first (?) My output should then look like:

```
FILE1
Z1 10 20 44 3
Z1 10 21 44 5
Z1 10 21 44 8
Z1 10 22 45 10
```

Is there a simple solution to this?

Comment: This seems like a job for [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/).

Comment: How much more work are you likely to do? If this is really all you need, @r-phillip-castagna 's solution is compact; if you're likely to insert a bit more work, farmer-joe has organized it flexibly; and if you're going to want to do a lot of alteration and analysis, pandas is the way to go. Decisions, decisions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the header first, *then* initialize the reader, write the header first, *then* initialize the writer:

```
import csv

with open("in.csv", "rb") as in_file:
    header = in_file.readline()
    csv_file_in = csv.reader(in_file, delimiter=" ")
    with open("out.csv","wb") as out_file:
        out_file.write(header)
        csv_file_out = csv.writer(out_file, delimiter=" ")
        for row in csv_file_in:
            csv_file_out.writerow([row[0], 10] + row[1:])
```

Comment: Thanks :) I think this is the closest to correct I have tested so far, the only issue is that at the end of each line in the output file I get '<cr>'. 
How do I get rid of that?

Comment: You use Windows, I presume? See if the edit I made (reading and writing in binary mode) fixes it.

Comment: I am using Linux; tried using "rb" and "wb", it is still the same. Any other clues?

Comment: Is it possible your files came from Windows? A carriage-return usually comes from using Windows, since they use CR-LF instead of just LF for a line break. But wait, you don't get CRs in the input file? Wait a sec, let me try the script on my Linux server.

Comment: Weird, it works flawlessly on my Linux server. Are you sure you don't have CRs in your original file?

Comment: Also, please check the version of Python you're using. Runs fine for me on Python 2.7 and Python 3.4; I think I remember something with csv having changed in Python 2.5…

Comment: I am using Python 2.7.6, and no I don't have CR's in my input file. I created it in Linux, so I can't really see how this is Windows related... but then again, I'm quite new to programming. 

Is there a way to get around this? Anyway, in terms of methodology your answer did help med solve it, so I'll just accept your answer.

Answer (score 3):

I think the easiest solution would be to just read each row and write a corresponding new row (with the inserted value) in a new file:

```
import csv
with open('input.csv', 'r') as infile:
     with open('output.csv', 'w') as outfile:
         reader = csv.reader(infile, delimiter=' ')
         writer = csv.writer(outfile, delimiter=' ')
         for row in reader: 
             new_row = [row[0], 10]
             new_row += row[1:]
             writer.writerow(new_row)
```

This might not make sense if you're not doing anything else with the data besides this bulk processing, though. You'd' want to look into csv libraries if that were the case.

Answer (score 3):

Use `pandas` to import the csv file as a `DataFrame` named `df` and then use `df.insert(idx, col_name, value)`; where `idx` is the index of the newly created column, `col_name` is the name you assign to this column and `value` is the list of values you wish to assign to the column. See below for illustration:

```
import pandas as pd

prices = pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\\abdou.seck\\Documents\\prices.csv')

prices

## Output
  Shares  Number  Prices
0    AAP     100  100.67
1   MSFT      50   56.50
2    SAN     200   19.18
3   GOOG     300  500.34

prices.insert(3, 'Total', prices['Number']*prices['Prices'])

prices

## Output:
  Shares  Number  Prices   Total
0    AAP     100  100.67   10067
1   MSFT      50   56.50    2825
2    SAN     200   19.18    3836
3   GOOG     300  500.34  150102
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Pull the data into a `list`, insert data for each row into the desired spot, and re-write the data.

```
import csv

data_to_add = 10    
new_column_index = 1   # 0 based index

with open('FILE1.csv','r') as f:
    csv_r = csv.reader(f,delimiter=' ')
    data = [line for line in csv_r]

for row in data:
    row.insert(new_column_index,data_to_add)

with open('FILE1.csv','w') as f:
    csv_w = csv.writer(f,delimiter=' ')
    for row in data:
        csv_w.write(row)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I might do it with pandas:

```
import pandas as pd

with open("in.csv") as input_file:
    header = input_file.readline()
    data = pd.read_csv(input_file, sep=" ")

data.insert(1, "New Data", 10)

with open("out.csv", "w") as output_file:
    output_file.write(header)
    data.to_csv(output_file, index=False, header=False)
```